# Add multiple relational data into SQL server using EF core

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to insert multiple relational data into SQL server DB using EF core 5.
I want to insert multiple parents with multiple child. Parents and child has one to many relationship. I am trying to add it using
context.AddRang(lstparents)
It is inserting child entity data only for one parents and for rest of the parents there is no entry. Could you please help me to resolve this issue.

My Models

```
    Public class Parent
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      Public int64 Id {get; set;}// this is identity column
    
      Public string Name { get; set;}
    
      Public List<Child> child { get; set;}
    }

    Public class Child
    {
       [Key]
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       Public int64 id { get; set;} // identity column
       Public string ChildName { get; set;}
    
       Public int64 ParentId { get; set;}
    
       [Foreign key("ParentId")]
       Public Parent parent { get; set;}
    }


// Here is insertion logic

Public void main(string[] args)
{

List<Child> lstChild = new List<Child> () 
                      { 
                        new Child{ ChildName= "Child1Name"}, 
                        new Child{ ChildName= "Child2Name"}, 
                        new Child{ ChildName= "Child3Name"} 
                      }; 
List<Parent> lstparents = new List<Parent>()
                       { 
                        new Parent {Name = "xyz", Child= lstChild }, 
                        new Parent {Name = "xyz1", Child= lstChild} 
                       };
Context.AddRangeAsync(lstparents); 
Context.SaveChangesAsync();


}
```

I have tried below options as well but I ran into another problem.

**Option 1:**

```
Public void main(string[] args)
    {
    
    List<Child> lstChild = new List<Child> () 
                          { 
                            new Child{ ChildName= "Child1Name"}, 
                            new Child{ ChildName= "Child2Name"}, 
                            new Child{ ChildName= "Child3Name"} 
                          }; 
    List<Parent> lstparents = new List<Parent>()
                           { 
                            new Parent {Name = "xyz", Child= lstChild }, 
                            new Parent {Name = "xyz1", Child= lstChild} 
                           };
    foreach(var item in lstparents)
    {
        Context.Add(item); 
        foreach(var child in lstChild)
        {
            Context.Add(child); 
         }
     }
     Context.SaveChangesAsync();   
    }
```

**option2:**
In below line of code i am getting an error
**"Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF"**

Public void main(string[] args)
{

```
    List<Child> lstChild = new List<Child> () 
                          { 
                            new Child{ ChildName= "Child1Name"}, 
                            new Child{ ChildName= "Child2Name"}, 
                            new Child{ ChildName= "Child3Name"} 
                          }; 
    List<Parent> lstparents = new List<Parent>()
                           { 
                            new Parent {Name = "xyz", Child= lstChild }, 
                            new Parent {Name = "xyz1", Child= lstChild} 
                           };
    foreach(var item in lstparents)
    {
        Context.Entry(item).State=EntityState.Added; 
        foreach(var child in lstChild)
        {
            Context.Entry(child).State=EntityState.Added; 
         }
     }
     Context.SaveChangesAsync();   
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have one-to-many relations (one parent can have many children) you can't add one child set to many parents. If you neeed it , you need to configure many-to-many relations. So if you want to add 2 parents you will have to create 2 lists of children, not one

```
List<Child> childList1 = new List<Child> () 
                      { 
                        new Child{ ChildName= "Child1Name"}, 
                        new Child{ ChildName= "Child2Name"}, 
                        new Child{ ChildName= "Child3Name"} 
                      }; 
List<Child> childList2 = new List<Child> () 
                      { 
                        new Child{ ChildName= "Child4Name"}, 
                        new Child{ ChildName= "Child5Name"}, 
                        new Child{ ChildName= "Child6Name"} 
                      }; 
List<Parent> lstparents = new List<Parent>()
                       { 
                        new Parent {Name = "parent1", Child= childList1 }, 
                        new Parent {Name = "parent2", Child= childList2 } 
                       };
```

and since your main is not async you can only use sync operations

```
Context.AddRange(lstparents); 
Context.SaveChanges();
```

and IMHO maybe it is a good idea to make ParentId nullable

```
 public long? ParentId { get; set;}
```

and if you need to add many to many you need  to add a ParentChild table.

If you use net5+ , ef core can add it for you , you just need to change navigaion properties

```
 Public class Parent
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
      public long Id {get; set;}// this is identity column
    
      public string Name { get; set;}
    
      public virtual ICollection<Child> Childs { get; set;}
    }

    Public class Child
    {
       [Key]
       [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
       public long Id { get; set;} // identity column
       public string ChildName { get; set;}
          
       public virtual ICollecton<Parent> Parents { get; set;}
    }
```

Comment: As you rightly said I need to have one parent and many children. In my case I would like to add same children with different primary key to different parent. My Child list will be same but while inserting in DB it has different primary key for each parent. Can we do that in EF Core.

Comment: @user1776386 I updated my answer. After this you will have to make a clean migration to  Db again.

Comment: @user1776386 *"I would like to add **same** children with **different** primary key to different parent"* They are *not* the same if PK (entity identity) is different. Having same Name and other properties does not make them *same*. Use **separate** objects and lists as Serge showed at the beginning of the answer.